# Add self signed certificate using retrofit call

Tags: android, ssl, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to add self signed certificate using retrofit, for that I need to pass context but facing some problems passing context through MVC model

Retrofit Client

```
object RetrofitClient    {
  fun call(context: Context): Webservice {
    val webservice by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            //  .baseUrl("http://68.183.183.255:8080")
            //.baseUrl("http://my-json-server.typicode.com")
            .baseUrl("https://54roh005p5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mdv/cloud/login/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .client(SelfSigningClientBuilder.createClient(context))
            .build().create(Webservice::class.java)
    }
    return webservice
  }
}
```

Repository

```
class TodoRepository(context:Context) {

   private var client:Webservice = RetrofitClient.call(context)
   //suspend fun getTodo(id: String) = client.getTodo(id)
   suspend fun getTodo(id: User) = client.getTodo(id)
}
```

ViewModel

```
class NetworkViewModel(context: Context) : ViewModel() {

  var repository: TodoRepository  = TodoRepository(context)
  fun getTodo(arg : User):LiveData<Response<com.example.myapplication.entity.UserData>> {
    val result = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val retrivedTodo = repository.getTodo(arg)

        emit(retrivedTodo)
      }
    return result
   }
}
```

MainActivity

`networkViewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NetworkViewModel(this)::class.java)`

It is giving the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myapplication.network.NetworkViewModel
```

what am i doing wrong. If there is a better method please suggest it

Comment: Why you pass Context to every Class? Just create an application class and get context from there

Comment: i tried that it is giving me error
MyApp.getContext() must not be null

Comment: Add your **MyApp** code. I will update

Comment: class MainApplication : Application() {

    init {
        instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: MainApplication? = null

        fun applicationContext() : Context {
            return instance!!.applicationContext
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val context: Context = MainApplication.applicationContext()
    }
}

Comment: class MainApplication : Application() { 
    companion object { 
        private lateinit var instance: MainApplication
        
        fun applicationContext() : Context { 
            return instance.applicationContext
        } 
    } 
    
    override fun onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    } 
}

Comment: then call **MainApplication.applicationContext()** to get Context

Comment: still giving error      Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property instance has not been initialized

Comment: That means you haven't set **MainApplication** as your default application in **AndroidManifet**

Comment: In **AndroidManifest**'s application tag add this `android:name=".MainApplication"`. Package name may vary

Comment: thanks a lot , it is showing a memory leak warning shouldn't it be problem

Comment: Is it solve your problem?

Comment: partially now working on ssl

Comment: can the line be changed to         private lateinit var instance: Application?

Comment: Check my answer, I have posted it

Comment: Yes, you can change like this: `private lateinit var instance: Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather passing context from class to class it is good to make an application class and use this application context when required. Please check below:

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: MainApplication

        fun applicationContext() : Context {
            return instance.applicationContext
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }
}
```

Then, In `AndroidManifest`'s application tag add this `android:name=".MainApplication"`

Then call MainApplication.applicationContext() to get Context from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Dont initialize ViewModel object through constructor :- `NetworkViewModel(this)::class.java` is wrong. Use :-

```
 networkViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NetworkViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your OkHttpClients `sslSocketFactory`

e.g(`Retrofit`'s client setting)

```
val retrofit Retrofit
    .Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

e.g(`OkHttpsClient`'s sslSocketFactory setting)

```
  val client =OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(sslContextWithSS.getSocketFactory())
            .build()
```

e.g(`SSLSocketFactory` with Custom Certificate)

```
        val keyStore = readKeyStore() //your method to obtain KeyStore
        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore)
        val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "keystore_pass".toCharArray())
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), SecureRandom())
        client.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
```

Getting `KeyStore` with your `CustomCertificate`

```
 fun readKeyStore()= KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()).also{
  try (val inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.custom_certificate)) {
        it.load(inputStream, getPassword());
    }
}
```